# git going back couple of commits on a branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I am very new to git, I checked couple of similiar questions, but, the ones I saw was slightly different, and I didn't get a strong grasp about them, so I am posting my own question.

I am sole developer on my project. I like to experiment frequently with my code, so I thought using a version control system would help. I have master branch, and a branch with a new feature I am working on. After branching out, I made some commits on feature branch that I would like to keep, and couple others I would like to discard. In the meantime, master was intact if that is relevant. I would like to find a way to learn how many commits should I go back on feature branch and also find a way to go to that commit. I can understand it by looking at commit messages but, I don't know where to see them.

Comment: Do you want to keep the original feature branch as it is?  Or is it OK to remove the unwanted commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working alone, easiest way ( and also keep your history clean) would be:

```
git reset --hard <commit hash of the commit before the commits you want to discard>
```

To get the hash use `git log` ( or `git log --pretty=oneline`) If you don't want to use hash, but know that it is four commits from HEAD, you use notations like `HEAD~4`

Or do `git rebase -i <hash as above>` and remove the lines representing the commits you want removed and do the rebase.

If you want to keep history ( and also if you were working with others, pushed to remote etc.) `git revert` is the safer solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. I'd recommend a [`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) if you want to discard the changes. Revert is sort of like undoing the work; it basically does a commit that undoes an existing commit. The nice part about this is, if you change your mind again later on, you can revert a revert!

If you want to revert more than one commit, which it sounds like you want to, the syntax looks something like this:

```
git revert branchname~5..branchname~3
```

This will revert the 5th last commit up to the 3rd last commit. `git revert` will immediately commit the revert. If you want to see the changes it will make before committing; then you can specify `--no-commit`, then commit it yourself later using `git commit`.

You can also revert individual commits like so:

```
git revert branchname~5
```

If you want to see all of the commits you've made so far, you can use `git log`.

And finally, using `git log` you can see the commit hash. git-revert can also accept a hash so you don't have to count how many revisions back it is.

```
git revert sha1hashhere
```

Comment: I read the logs and decided I need to go back 12 commit backwards, should I issue "git revert branchname~12..branchname~0"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with deleting the unwanted commits

1. Find the common parent the two have. *You can skip this step if you know far far back you want to go.*
   `git merge-base featureBranch masterBranch`
2. Checkout your featureBranch
   `git checkout featureBranch`
3. Rebase that branch, removing the commits you don't want (delete the lines that contain your unwanted commits when your editor pops up.
   `git rebase -i sha_from_step_1` or you can use `git rebase -i HEAD@{n}` where n is how far back you want to go.
4. Merge into master
   `git merge master`

Answer (score -1):

one comit back = HEAD^

two commit back = HEAD^^

read mapage "man gitrevisions"